# Getting correct index for strings with double byte characters

Tags: regex, go

Incorrect index:

```
r, _ := regexp.Compile("hot")
s := "it‘s hot"
fmt.Println(r.FindStringIndex(s))

[7 10]
```

Correct index:

```
r, _ := regexp.Compile("hot")
s := "it‘s hot"
s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "‘", "'")
fmt.Println(r.FindStringIndex(s))

[5 8]
```

As you can see the character '‘' is causing the problem. The question is: Is there a more generic solution to this problem? Or do we have to go down the path of collecting strings like this and create our own custom replace function for such characters.

Comment: Go "Index" functions return byte indexes. How to work with this depends on what you're doing. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes, thats what I thought. I need character indexes.

Comment: Could you solve your problem another way? You mention "custom replace function" but replace works fine. What are you using the character indexes for?

Comment: You know that "character" is a gross oversimplification leading to ugly bugs when working on Unicode texts? Do you know how many "characters" are the UTF-32 (for your convenience) byte string `1F926  1F3FC  200D  2640  FE0F`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the length of a string in runes (unicode characters) by using [`utf8.RuneCountInString`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneCountInString). You can use this in conjunction with string slicing to get the rune indices from byte indices:

```
r, _ := regexp.Compile("hot")
s := "it‘s hot"
idx := r.FindStringIndex(s)
fmt.Println(utf8.RuneCountInString(s[:idx[0]]), utf8.RuneCountInString(s[:idx[1]]))
```

Outputs:

```
5 8
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/6JSz5Mf2OHM

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "strings"

func runeIndex(s, substr string) int {
   n := strings.Index(s, substr)
   if n == -1 { return -1 }
   r := []rune(s[:n])
   return len(r)
}

func main() {
   n := runeIndex("it‘s hot", "hot")
   println(n == 5)
}
```